# How to derive BaseAdapter and customise the view without XML?

Tags: android

I do not want to reference a resource ( aka XML Layout ) for the view and even do not want to use inflater service.

I've seen many pages for list view example, but everyone seems to deriving their class from ArrayAdapter or CursorAdapter at the most.

So, can anyone show me an example on how to derive a class from BaseAdapter and make customised list views in it by modifying its 'getView' method ?

Comment: What is your issue with ArrayAdapter or CursorAdapter. Please specify what your requirement say for which you are going against convention

Comment: The issue with ArrayAdapter is as explained above, that I do not want to deal with XML for its generation of views. Issue, with CursorAdapter, is that I am not going to deal with SQL db pretty much here, as I need a simple implementation of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Views and set their properties programmatically in Java. It's almost the same as using AWT/Swing, if you're familiar with that.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<String> items; // could be an array/other structure 
                                // using Strings as example

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>(items);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    // notice I changed the return type from Object to String
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Really dumb implementation, you should use the convertView arg if it isn't null
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(getItem(position);
        /* call other setters on TextView */

        return textView;
    }
}
```

You may have to override some other methods but they should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to generate the list view without XML. However I do have another question. I am unable to add any other view like button, etc. onto  this textview that I prepare. How can I do this ? When I try to apply a layout parameter to the new button I create, then the app crashes.

Comment: You can't add a Button to a `TextView`. You would need to create a `LinearLayout` (or some other subclass of `ViewGroup`) and add your views to that. You would return the layout from `getView()`.